# Oracle query - How to count two distinct rows as one based on their value

Tags: oracle

I have table like this:

| id | physician | order_id | exam | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Physycian1 | 111 | TSH | 1 |
| 1 | Physycian1 | 111 | FT3 | 0 |
| 2 | Physycian1 | 112 | FT4 | 0 |
| 3 | Physycian1 | 112 | FT3 | 0 |
| 3 | Physycian1 | 113 | FT3 | 0 |
| 3 | Physycian1 | 113 | FT4 | 0 |

And I have query like this:

```
SELECT  
    physician, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT order_id) sum,
    CASE price 
        WHEN 0 THEN 'Free'
        ELSE 'Paid'
    END AS is_free
FROM
    table
GROUP BY
    physician,
    CASE price 
        WHEN 0 THEN 'Free'
        ELSE 'Paid'
    END
```

And the result is something like this:

| physician | sum | is_free |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Physician1 | 3 | Free |
| Physician1 | 1 | Paid |

How can I change this query to count order_id=111(and others that might appear in DB) only as Paid and not as both.

So the end result would be:

| physician | sum | is_free |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Physician1 | 2 | Free |
| Physician1 | 1 | Paid |

Comment: can you edit the last bit of your question so we can see the desired result

Comment: Sorry. Fixed. Weird thing because preview was showing it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First boil your data down to only one row per physician and order. Then count.

```
select physician, pay_mode, count(*)
from
(
  select
    physician,
    order_id,
    max(case when price = 0 then 'free' else 'paid' end) as pay_mode
  from mytable
  group by physician, order_id
) orders
group by physician, pay_mode
order by physician, pay_mode;
```

Comment: That's exactly what I've been looking for. Thank you very much.